# Prove that a random error and the fitted value of y are independent

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have a simple linear regression $y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x + \epsilon$ and the formula for the fitted regression $\hat y=\hat \beta_{0}+\hat \beta_{1}x$. The book takes for granted that the following is true $$\Bbb E[\epsilon \hat y]=\Bbb E[\epsilon]\Bbb E[\hat y]$$ and that means that $\epsilon,\hat y$ are independent random variables. Can you show me why this is true?

Comment: In my opinion the relation $\Bbb E[\epsilon \hat y]-\Bbb E[\epsilon]\Bbb E[\hat y]=0$ means only that $Cov(\epsilon, \hat y)=0$. From this fact you cannot conclude that $\epsilon, \hat y$ are independent: "If two variables are uncorrelated, that does not in general imply that they are independent" (copied from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Uncorrelatedness_and_independence) ).

Comment: I know. Do you know how to prove they are independent then? Because my teacher says they are but no explanation.

Comment: @Thomas If $\epsilon$ and $\hat{y}$ have joint multivariate normal distribution then $0$ covariance implies independence. Sometimes normality assumed as a part of the assumptions on $\epsilon$ and $x$, so it may solve the problem .

Comment: @Thomas : If the random errors are normally distributed and independent, then two linear combinations of them are independent of each other if their covariance is $0.$ Weaker assumptions on the joint distribution of the random errors do not result in independence of uncorrelated linear combinations.

Comment: @MichaelHardy What do you mean if the random errors are independent? That if $\epsilon_{1} , \epsilon_{2}$ are 2 random errors of 2 different observations then they are independent?

Comment: @Thomas : Yes. Except that it also applies to more than two.

Comment: OK, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat{Y}$ is projection of $Y$ onto $C(X)$, hence just show that 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon X]=0.
$$
Namely, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon X]=\mathbb{E}[Y - \beta_0 - \beta_1x |x] = \mathbb{E}[Y\mid x] - \mathbb{E}[\beta_0 + \beta_1x\mid x]
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon X]=\mathbb{E}[\beta_0 + \beta_1x\mid x]-\mathbb{E}[\beta_0 + \beta_1x\mid x]=0.
$$
I.e., it shows that $\operatorname{cov}(X,\epsilon)=0$, thus as $\hat{Y}$ is linear projection, $\hat{Y} = HY = f(X)$, $\operatorname{cov}(f(X),\epsilon)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm not really familiar with this subject, can you tell me what $X$ and $C(X)$ is?

Comment: Basically it is the design matrix, so I've slightly abused notation in the an answer switching between the matrix and the r.v.s. But in general, $\hat{y}$ is a linear projection onto the affine space that spanned by $\{1,x\}$, so the $0$ co-variance preserved.

Comment: I see, thank you. Also, covariance doesn't imply independency for sure. In this case, it's true though? The fact that $cov=0$ means that they are also independent?

Comment: Please see the comment above

Comment: This result is true for general linear model as well right? Not only for the simple.

Comment: Yes. $X$ might contain any $p$,  $p \ge 1$ explanatory variables.